# When downloaded code from SourceForge does not reflect the latest edits, what could be the issue and how can I solve it?

Tags: git, homebrew

In the following [sourceforge hosted libdc1394 library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libdc1394/), Damien Douxchamps correctly added some lines of code to /usb/control.c on 2014-3-6.    The latest [2.2.2 package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libdc1394/files/libdc1394-2/2.2.2/) of this library, was modified and released on the same date (2014-3-6), however, the `/usb/control.c` code in the downloaded `libdc1394-2.2.2.tar.gz` package does not reflect the changes made to `/usb/control.c` on the same date.

What is likely going on here and is there anything that I can do to reconcile this?  I am new to git and sourceforge.

I am using homebrew as a package manager, and it downloads and installs 2.2.2 just fine, but obviously 2.2.2 does not contain the appropriate changes to the code made on the same date.

here is a snippet from the homebrew formula:

```
  homepage "http://damien.douxchamps.net/ieee1394/libdc1394/"
  url "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libdc1394/libdc1394-2/2.2.2/libdc1394-2.2.2.tar.gz"
  sha1 "13958c3cd0709565b5e4a9012dcf2a9b710264e2"
```

this is the /usb/control.c code *on sourceforge* after the 2014-3-6 edit ("GOOD"):

```
/*
 * 1394-Based Digital Camera Control Library
 *
 * IIDC-over-USB using libusb backend for dc1394
 *
 * Written by David Moore <dcm@acm.org>
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include "config.h"
#include "platform.h"
#include "internal.h"
#include "usb.h"


static platform_t *
dc1394_usb_new (void)
{
    libusb_context *context;
    if (libusb_init(&context) != 0)
        return NULL;

    platform_t * p = calloc (1, sizeof (platform_t));
    p->context = context;
    return p;
}
static void
dc1394_usb_free (platform_t * p)
{
    if (p->context)
        libusb_exit(p->context);
    p->context = NULL;
    free (p);
}

struct _platform_device_t {
    libusb_device * dev;
};

typedef struct _usb_device_list_t {
    platform_device_list_t list;
    libusb_device ** libusb_list;
} usb_device_list_t;

/* This is the list of USB vendor/products that we know support
 * IIDC-over-USB.  Currently, this is the only mechanism of detecting
 * such cameras. */
static struct _vendor_product_t {
    uint16_t vendor;
    uint16_t product;
} usb_products[] = {
    { 0x1e10, 0x2000 }, // Point Grey Firefly MV Color
    { 0x1e10, 0x2001 }, // Point Grey Firefly MV Mono
    { 0x1e10, 0x2002 }, // Point Grey High Res Firefly MV Color
    { 0x1e10, 0x2003 }, // Point Grey High Res Firefly MV Mono
    { 0x1e10, 0x2004 }, // Point Grey Chameleon Color
    { 0x1e10, 0x2005 }, // Point Grey Chameleon Mono
    { 0x1e10, 0x3000 }, // Point Grey Flea 3
    { 0x1e10, 0x3005 }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-13Y3M)
    { 0x1e10, 0x3006 }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-13S2C)
    { 0x1e10, 0x3008 }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-88S2C)
    { 0x1e10, 0x300a }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-13E4C)
    { 0, 0 }
};

static int
is_device_iidc (uint16_t vendor, uint16_t product)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (usb_products[j].vendor != 0 && usb_products[j].product != 0) {
        if (usb_products[j].vendor == vendor &&
                usb_products[j].product == product)
            return 1;
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}

static platform_device_list_t *
dc1394_usb_get_device_list (platform_t * p)
{
    usb_device_list_t * list;
    libusb_device * dev;
    int i;

    list = calloc (1, sizeof (usb_device_list_t));
    if (!list)
        return NULL;

    if (libusb_get_device_list (p->context, &list->libusb_list) < 0)
        return NULL;

    dev = list->libusb_list[0];
    for (i=0, dev = list->libusb_list[0]; dev; dev = list->libusb_list[++i]) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        if (libusb_get_device_descriptor (dev, &desc) != 0) {
            dc1394_log_warning ("usb: Failed to get descriptor for device %d",
                    i);
            continue;
        }

        if (!is_device_iidc (desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct))
            continue;

        list->list.num_devices++;
        list->list.devices = realloc (list->list.devices,
                list->list.num_devices * sizeof (platform_device_t *));
        platform_device_t * pdev = malloc(sizeof(platform_device_t));
        pdev->dev = dev;
        list->list.devices[list->list.num_devices-1] = pdev;

        dc1394_log_debug ("usb: Found vendor:prod %x:%x at address %x:%x",
                desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
                libusb_get_bus_number (dev), libusb_get_device_address (dev));
    }

    return &list->list;
}

static void
dc1394_usb_free_device_list (platform_device_list_t * d)
{
    usb_device_list_t * list = (usb_device_list_t *) d;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < d->num_devices; i++)
        free (d->devices[i]);
    free (d->devices);
    libusb_free_device_list (list->libusb_list, 1);
    free (d);
}

/* The high 16 bits of the IEEE 1394 address space are mapped to the request
 * byte of USB control transfers.  Only a discrete set addresses are
 * currently supported, as mapped by this function. */
static int
address_to_request (uint64_t address)
{
    switch (address >> 32) {
        case 0xffff:
            return 0x7f;
        case 0xd000:
            return 0x80;
        case 0xd0001:
            return 0x81;
    }
    dc1394_log_error("usb: Invalid high address %x for request",
            address >> 32);
    return -1;
}

#define REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS  1000

static int
do_read (libusb_device_handle * handle, uint64_t address, uint32_t * quads,
        int num_quads)
{
    int request = address_to_request (address);
    if (request < 0)
        return -1;

    unsigned char buf[num_quads*4];

    /* IEEE 1394 address reads are mapped to USB control transfers as
     * shown here. */
    int ret = libusb_control_transfer (handle, 0xc0, request,
            address & 0xffff, (address >> 16) & 0xffff,
            buf, num_quads * 4, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS);
    if (ret < 0)
        return -1;
    int i;
    int ret_quads = (ret + 3) / 4;
    /* Convert from little-endian to host-endian */
    for (i = 0; i < ret_quads; i++) {
        quads[i] = (buf[4*i+3] << 24) | (buf[4*i+2] << 16)
            | (buf[4*i+1] << 8) | buf[4*i];
    }
    return ret_quads;
}

static int
do_write (libusb_device_handle * handle, uint64_t address,
        const uint32_t * quads, int num_quads)
{
    int request = address_to_request (address);
    if (request < 0)
        return -1;

    unsigned char buf[num_quads*4];
    int i;
    /* Convert from host-endian to little-endian */
    for (i = 0; i < num_quads; i++) {
        buf[4*i]   = quads[i] & 0xff;
        buf[4*i+1] = (quads[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
        buf[4*i+2] = (quads[i] >> 16) & 0xff;
        buf[4*i+3] = (quads[i] >> 24) & 0xff;
    }
    /* IEEE 1394 address writes are mapped to USB control transfers as
     * shown here. */
    int ret = libusb_control_transfer (handle, 0x40, request,
            address & 0xffff, (address >> 16) & 0xffff,
            buf, num_quads * 4, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS);
    if (ret < 0)
        return -1;
    return ret / 4;
}

static int
dc1394_usb_device_get_config_rom (platform_device_t * device,
                                uint32_t * quads, int * num_quads)
{
    libusb_device_handle * handle;
    if (libusb_open (device->dev, &handle) < 0) {
        dc1394_log_warning ("usb: Failed to open device for config ROM");
        return DC1394_FAILURE;
    }

    if (*num_quads > 256)
        *num_quads = 256;

    /* Read the config ROM one quad at a time because a read longer than
     * the length of the ROM will fail. */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *num_quads; i++) {
        int ret = do_read (handle, CONFIG_ROM_BASE + 0x400 + 4*i,
                quads + i, 1);
        if (ret < 1)
            break;
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        dc1394_log_error ("usb: Failed to read config ROM");
        libusb_close (handle);
        return -1;
    }

    *num_quads = i;
    libusb_close (handle);
    return 0;
}

static platform_camera_t *
dc1394_usb_camera_new (platform_t * p, platform_device_t * device,
        uint32_t unit_directory_offset)
{
    libusb_device_handle * handle;
    platform_camera_t * camera;

    if (libusb_open (device->dev, &handle) < 0) {
        dc1394_log_error ("usb: Failed to open device");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (libusb_set_configuration (handle, 1) < 0) {
        dc1394_log_error ("usb: Failed to set configuration 1 after open");
        libusb_close (handle);
        return NULL;
    }

    camera = calloc (1, sizeof (platform_camera_t));
    camera->handle = handle;
    return camera;
}

static void dc1394_usb_camera_free (platform_camera_t * cam)
{
    libusb_close (cam->handle);
    cam->handle = NULL;
    free (cam);
}

static void
dc1394_usb_camera_set_parent (platform_camera_t * cam, dc1394camera_t * parent)
{
    cam->camera = parent;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_camera_print_info (platform_camera_t * camera, FILE *fd)
{
    libusb_device *dev = libusb_get_device (camera->handle);
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    libusb_get_device_descriptor (dev, &desc);
    fprintf(fd,"------ Camera platform-specific information ------\n");
    fprintf(fd,"USB Bus Number                    :     %d\n",
            libusb_get_bus_number (dev));
    fprintf(fd,"USB Device Address                :     %d\n",
            libusb_get_device_address (dev));
    fprintf(fd,"Vendor ID                         :     0x%x\n",
            desc.idVendor);
    fprintf(fd,"Product ID                        :     0x%x\n",
            desc.idProduct);
    return DC1394_SUCCESS;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_camera_read (platform_camera_t * cam, uint64_t offset,
        uint32_t * quads, int num_quads)
{
    if (do_read (cam->handle, CONFIG_ROM_BASE + offset, quads,
                num_quads) != num_quads)
        return DC1394_FAILURE;

    return DC1394_SUCCESS;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_camera_write (platform_camera_t * cam, uint64_t offset,
        const uint32_t * quads, int num_quads)
{
    if (do_write (cam->handle, CONFIG_ROM_BASE + offset, quads,
                num_quads) != num_quads)
        return DC1394_FAILURE;

    return DC1394_SUCCESS;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_camera_get_node(platform_camera_t *cam, uint32_t *node,
        uint32_t * generation)
{
    /* Since node/generation doesn't really apply to USB, we instead
     * put the device address in the "node" argument and "bus number"
     * in the generation argument. */
    if (node)
        *node = libusb_get_device_address (libusb_get_device (cam->handle));
    if (generation)
        *generation = libusb_get_bus_number (libusb_get_device (cam->handle));
    return DC1394_SUCCESS;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_reset_bus (platform_camera_t * cam)
{
    int ret = libusb_reset_device (cam->handle);
    if (ret == 0 || ret == LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
        return DC1394_SUCCESS;

    return DC1394_FAILURE;
}

static platform_dispatch_t
usb_dispatch = {
    .platform_new = dc1394_usb_new,
    .platform_free = dc1394_usb_free,

    .get_device_list = dc1394_usb_get_device_list,
    .free_device_list = dc1394_usb_free_device_list,
    .device_get_config_rom = dc1394_usb_device_get_config_rom,

    .camera_new = dc1394_usb_camera_new,
    .camera_free = dc1394_usb_camera_free,
    .camera_set_parent = dc1394_usb_camera_set_parent,

    .camera_print_info = dc1394_usb_camera_print_info,
    .camera_get_node = dc1394_usb_camera_get_node,
    .reset_bus = dc1394_usb_reset_bus,

    .camera_read = dc1394_usb_camera_read,
    .camera_write = dc1394_usb_camera_write,

    .capture_setup = dc1394_usb_capture_setup,
    .capture_stop = dc1394_usb_capture_stop,
    .capture_dequeue = dc1394_usb_capture_dequeue,
    .capture_enqueue = dc1394_usb_capture_enqueue,
    .capture_get_fileno = dc1394_usb_capture_get_fileno,
    .capture_is_frame_corrupt = dc1394_usb_capture_is_frame_corrupt,

#ifdef HAVE_MACOSX
    .capture_set_callback = dc1394_usb_capture_set_callback,
    .capture_schedule_with_runloop = dc1394_usb_capture_schedule_with_runloop,
#else
    .capture_set_callback = NULL,
    .capture_schedule_with_runloop = NULL,
#endif
};

void
dc1394_usb_init(dc1394_t * d)
{
    register_platform (d, &usb_dispatch, "usb");
}
```

this is the /usb/control.c code in 2.2.2 package released on 2014-3-6 ("BAD"):

```
/*
 * 1394-Based Digital Camera Control Library
 *
 * IIDC-over-USB using libusb backend for dc1394
 *
 * Written by David Moore <dcm@acm.org>
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include "config.h"
#include "platform.h"
#include "internal.h"
#include "usb.h"


static platform_t *
dc1394_usb_new (void)
{
    libusb_context *context;
    if (libusb_init(&context) != 0)
        return NULL;

    platform_t * p = calloc (1, sizeof (platform_t));
    p->context = context;
    return p;
}
static void
dc1394_usb_free (platform_t * p)
{
    if (p->context)
        libusb_exit(p->context);
    p->context = NULL;
    free (p);
}

struct _platform_device_t {
    libusb_device * dev;
};

typedef struct _usb_device_list_t {
    platform_device_list_t list;
    libusb_device ** libusb_list;
} usb_device_list_t;

/* This is the list of USB vendor/products that we know support
 * IIDC-over-USB.  Currently, this is the only mechanism of detecting
 * such cameras. */
static struct _vendor_product_t {
    uint16_t vendor;
    uint16_t product;
} usb_products[] = {
    { 0x1e10, 0x2000 }, // Point Grey Firefly MV Color
    { 0x1e10, 0x2001 }, // Point Grey Firefly MV Mono
    { 0x1e10, 0x2002 }, // Point Grey High Res Firefly MV Color
    { 0x1e10, 0x2003 }, // Point Grey High Res Firefly MV Mono
    { 0x1e10, 0x2004 }, // Point Grey Chameleon Color
    { 0x1e10, 0x2005 }, // Point Grey Chameleon Mono
    { 0x1e10, 0x3000 }, // Point Grey Flea 3
    { 0x1e10, 0x3005 }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-13Y3M)
    { 0x1e10, 0x3006 }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-13S2C)
    { 0x1e10, 0x3008 }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-88S2C)
    { 0x1e10, 0x300a }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-13E4C)
    { 0x1e10, 0x300b }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-13E4M with 1.43.3.2 FW)
    { 0x1e10, 0x3300 }, // Point Grey Flea 3 (FL3-U3-13E4M with 2.7.3.0 FW)
    { 0, 0 }
};

static int
is_device_iidc (uint16_t vendor, uint16_t product)
{
    int j = 0;
    while (usb_products[j].vendor != 0 && usb_products[j].product != 0) {
        if (usb_products[j].vendor == vendor &&
                usb_products[j].product == product)
            return 1;
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}

static platform_device_list_t *
dc1394_usb_get_device_list (platform_t * p)
{
    usb_device_list_t * list;
    libusb_device * dev;
    int i;

    list = calloc (1, sizeof (usb_device_list_t));
    if (!list)
        return NULL;

    if (libusb_get_device_list (p->context, &list->libusb_list) < 0)
        return NULL;

    dev = list->libusb_list[0];
    for (i=0, dev = list->libusb_list[0]; dev; dev = list->libusb_list[++i]) {
        struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
        if (libusb_get_device_descriptor (dev, &desc) != 0) {
            dc1394_log_warning ("usb: Failed to get descriptor for device %d",
                    i);
            continue;
        }

        if (!is_device_iidc (desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct))
            continue;

        list->list.num_devices++;
        list->list.devices = realloc (list->list.devices,
                list->list.num_devices * sizeof (platform_device_t *));
        platform_device_t * pdev = malloc(sizeof(platform_device_t));
        pdev->dev = dev;
        list->list.devices[list->list.num_devices-1] = pdev;

        dc1394_log_debug ("usb: Found vendor:prod %x:%x at address %x:%x",
                desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct,
                libusb_get_bus_number (dev), libusb_get_device_address (dev));
    }

    return &list->list;
}

static void
dc1394_usb_free_device_list (platform_device_list_t * d)
{
    usb_device_list_t * list = (usb_device_list_t *) d;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < d->num_devices; i++)
        free (d->devices[i]);
    free (d->devices);
    libusb_free_device_list (list->libusb_list, 1);
    free (d);
}

/* The high 16 bits of the IEEE 1394 address space are mapped to the request
 * byte of USB control transfers.  Only a discrete set addresses are
 * currently supported, as mapped by this function. */
static int
address_to_request (uint64_t address)
{
    switch (address >> 32) {
        case 0xffff:
            return 0x7f;
        case 0xd000:
            return 0x80;
        case 0xd0001:
            return 0x81;
    }
    dc1394_log_error("usb: Invalid high address %x for request",
            address >> 32);
    return -1;
}

#define REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS  1000

static int
do_read (libusb_device_handle * handle, uint64_t address, uint32_t * quads,
        int num_quads)
{
    int request = address_to_request (address);
    if (request < 0)
        return -1;

    unsigned char buf[num_quads*4];

    /* IEEE 1394 address reads are mapped to USB control transfers as
     * shown here. */
    int ret = libusb_control_transfer (handle, 0xc0, request,
            address & 0xffff, (address >> 16) & 0xffff,
            buf, num_quads * 4, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS);
    if (ret < 0)
        return -1;
    int i;
    int ret_quads = (ret + 3) / 4;
    /* Convert from little-endian to host-endian */
    for (i = 0; i < ret_quads; i++) {
        quads[i] = (buf[4*i+3] << 24) | (buf[4*i+2] << 16)
            | (buf[4*i+1] << 8) | buf[4*i];
    }
    return ret_quads;
}

static int
do_write (libusb_device_handle * handle, uint64_t address,
        const uint32_t * quads, int num_quads)
{
    int request = address_to_request (address);
    if (request < 0)
        return -1;

    unsigned char buf[num_quads*4];
    int i;
    /* Convert from host-endian to little-endian */
    for (i = 0; i < num_quads; i++) {
        buf[4*i]   = quads[i] & 0xff;
        buf[4*i+1] = (quads[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
        buf[4*i+2] = (quads[i] >> 16) & 0xff;
        buf[4*i+3] = (quads[i] >> 24) & 0xff;
    }
    /* IEEE 1394 address writes are mapped to USB control transfers as
     * shown here. */
    int ret = libusb_control_transfer (handle, 0x40, request,
            address & 0xffff, (address >> 16) & 0xffff,
            buf, num_quads * 4, REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS);
    if (ret < 0)
        return -1;
    return ret / 4;
}

static int
dc1394_usb_device_get_config_rom (platform_device_t * device,
                                uint32_t * quads, int * num_quads)
{
    libusb_device_handle * handle;
    if (libusb_open (device->dev, &handle) < 0) {
        dc1394_log_warning ("usb: Failed to open device for config ROM");
        return DC1394_FAILURE;
    }

    if (*num_quads > 256)
        *num_quads = 256;

    /* Read the config ROM one quad at a time because a read longer than
     * the length of the ROM will fail. */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *num_quads; i++) {
        int ret = do_read (handle, CONFIG_ROM_BASE + 0x400 + 4*i,
                quads + i, 1);
        if (ret < 1)
            break;
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        dc1394_log_error ("usb: Failed to read config ROM");
        libusb_close (handle);
        return -1;
    }

    *num_quads = i;
    libusb_close (handle);
    return 0;
}

static platform_camera_t *
dc1394_usb_camera_new (platform_t * p, platform_device_t * device,
        uint32_t unit_directory_offset)
{
    libusb_device_handle * handle;
    platform_camera_t * camera;

    if (libusb_open (device->dev, &handle) < 0) {
        dc1394_log_error ("usb: Failed to open device");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (libusb_set_configuration (handle, 1) < 0) {
        dc1394_log_error ("usb: Failed to set configuration 1 after open");
        libusb_close (handle);
        return NULL;
    }

    camera = calloc (1, sizeof (platform_camera_t));
    camera->handle = handle;
    return camera;
}

static void dc1394_usb_camera_free (platform_camera_t * cam)
{
    libusb_close (cam->handle);
    cam->handle = NULL;
    free (cam);
}

static void
dc1394_usb_camera_set_parent (platform_camera_t * cam, dc1394camera_t * parent)
{
    cam->camera = parent;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_camera_print_info (platform_camera_t * camera, FILE *fd)
{
    libusb_device *dev = libusb_get_device (camera->handle);
    struct libusb_device_descriptor desc;
    libusb_get_device_descriptor (dev, &desc);
    fprintf(fd,"------ Camera platform-specific information ------\n");
    fprintf(fd,"USB Bus Number                    :     %d\n",
            libusb_get_bus_number (dev));
    fprintf(fd,"USB Device Address                :     %d\n",
            libusb_get_device_address (dev));
    fprintf(fd,"Vendor ID                         :     0x%x\n",
            desc.idVendor);
    fprintf(fd,"Product ID                        :     0x%x\n",
            desc.idProduct);
    return DC1394_SUCCESS;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_camera_read (platform_camera_t * cam, uint64_t offset,
        uint32_t * quads, int num_quads)
{
    if (do_read (cam->handle, CONFIG_ROM_BASE + offset, quads,
                num_quads) != num_quads)
        return DC1394_FAILURE;

    return DC1394_SUCCESS;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_camera_write (platform_camera_t * cam, uint64_t offset,
        const uint32_t * quads, int num_quads)
{
    if (do_write (cam->handle, CONFIG_ROM_BASE + offset, quads,
                num_quads) != num_quads)
        return DC1394_FAILURE;

    return DC1394_SUCCESS;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_camera_get_node(platform_camera_t *cam, uint32_t *node,
        uint32_t * generation)
{
    /* Since node/generation doesn't really apply to USB, we instead
     * put the device address in the "node" argument and "bus number"
     * in the generation argument. */
    if (node)
        *node = libusb_get_device_address (libusb_get_device (cam->handle));
    if (generation)
        *generation = libusb_get_bus_number (libusb_get_device (cam->handle));
    return DC1394_SUCCESS;
}

static dc1394error_t
dc1394_usb_reset_bus (platform_camera_t * cam)
{
    int ret = libusb_reset_device (cam->handle);
    if (ret == 0 || ret == LIBUSB_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
        return DC1394_SUCCESS;

    return DC1394_FAILURE;
}

static platform_dispatch_t
usb_dispatch = {
    .platform_new = dc1394_usb_new,
    .platform_free = dc1394_usb_free,

    .get_device_list = dc1394_usb_get_device_list,
    .free_device_list = dc1394_usb_free_device_list,
    .device_get_config_rom = dc1394_usb_device_get_config_rom,

    .camera_new = dc1394_usb_camera_new,
    .camera_free = dc1394_usb_camera_free,
    .camera_set_parent = dc1394_usb_camera_set_parent,

    .camera_print_info = dc1394_usb_camera_print_info,
    .camera_get_node = dc1394_usb_camera_get_node,
    .reset_bus = dc1394_usb_reset_bus,

    .camera_read = dc1394_usb_camera_read,
    .camera_write = dc1394_usb_camera_write,

    .capture_setup = dc1394_usb_capture_setup,
    .capture_stop = dc1394_usb_capture_stop,
    .capture_dequeue = dc1394_usb_capture_dequeue,
    .capture_enqueue = dc1394_usb_capture_enqueue,
    .capture_get_fileno = dc1394_usb_capture_get_fileno,
    .capture_is_frame_corrupt = dc1394_usb_capture_is_frame_corrupt,

#ifdef HAVE_MACOSX
    .capture_set_callback = dc1394_usb_capture_set_callback,
    .capture_schedule_with_runloop = dc1394_usb_capture_schedule_with_runloop,
#else
    .capture_set_callback = NULL,
    .capture_schedule_with_runloop = NULL,
#endif
};

void
dc1394_usb_init(dc1394_t * d)
{
    register_platform (d, &usb_dispatch, "usb");
}
```

Comment: Just contact the person who did this.

Comment: having trouble to contact them so far, but since it is summer it could take a bit longer.  since I am so new to open source I was just wondering what the issue could be, and if there is something that I can do to enact his change, or likely very little that I can do.

Comment: Looking at the diff only 2 lines were added, and from what I read, 2 new product support has been added https://www.diffchecker.com/1h33bs90

Comment: I'm not familiar with sourceforge but maybe the tar.gz file wasn't created automatically from git but manually by the developer himself, so this might be just human error. Either way theres nothing you can do other than building the source yourself from git or waiting for a reply from the developer.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was to ask the owner of the project to update the release to 2.2.3 and add these changes.

homebrew uses ruby scripts for their formulae, and because I saw the 2.2.3 edit had occurred so recently, homebrew didn't have a chance to catch up.  I simply modified the ruby `libdc1397.rb` formula file (they are all located in `/usr/local/Library/Formula/`).  New formula are added by homebrew people, and in turn, these formula are updated on your own system with `brew update`).

Inside `libdc1397.rb`, I modified the URL part to reflect the new location of 2.2.3.  Below is the top part of the file.  I simply replaced any 2.2.2 with 2.2.3.

```
require "formula"

class Libdc1394 < Formula
  homepage "http://damien.douxchamps.net/ieee1394/libdc1394/"
  url "https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libdc1394/libdc1394-2/2.2.3/libdc1394-2.2.3.tar.gz"
  #sha1 "13958c3cd0709565b5e4a9012dcf2a9b710264e2"
```

As you can see above, I also commented out the sha1 cryptographic hash.  The sha1 hash is used as a "key" for security purposes and is computed based on the open-source code.  Since the code had changed, the necessary sha1 hash probably did too, so I commented it out and skipped this security aspect that open-source people use.  I think that there is a way to re-compute this sha1 hash of the new code and thus maintain this security feature, but I will have to learn that another time.

---

Another thing I learned is to use the parameters from the homebrew formula to compile the code without issue.  Before, `./configure` gave lots of errors and issues, but homebrew worked smoothly.  Taking a look at what homebrew was doing, I was able to pass parameters to `./configure` in order to get it to work.

Inside `libdc1397.rb`, I found the following code, which gave me the right parameters to use when `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` my own modifications to the code.  In this way in the future I wouldn't need to depend on new "official releases".

```
   def install
    system "./configure", "--disable-dependency-tracking",
                          "--prefix=#{prefix}",
                          ”—-disable-examples",
                          "--disable-sdltest"
    system "make install"
  end
```

Also, one more thing about `libdc1397` and installing it properly.  `./configure` (and `homebrew` I think) was NOT detecting `libusb`, still installing but skipping this vital piece.  You need to uninstall `libusb` using `homebrew`, and re-install `libusb` using `macports` (`sudo port libusb`).  This is essential for PointGrey cameras that do IEEE1397 over USB.